# How to correctly call PHP function with arguments from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So I am making a Rock Paper Scissors game. I want to make it that when the user loses to the computer, the game finishes or restars and the user's high score is updated in MySQL. I cannot seem to make it work tho. This is what I have so far:
The code is big so I will add a small part of it.

apps.js

```
function lose(user, computer) {
    compScore++;
    userScore_span.innerHTML = userScore;
    compScore_span.innerHTML = compScore;
    rezultat_p.innerHTML = convertWord(user) + " loses to " + convertWord(computer) + ". Game Over!";
    getOutput();
}

function getOutput() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'myAjax.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {functionname: 'gameOver', arguments: [userScore]},

        success: function (obj, textstatus) {
            if( !('error' in obj) ) {
                yourVariable = obj.result;
            }
            else {
                console.log(obj.error);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

myAjax.php

```
<?php

function gameOver($highScore){
    session_start();
    require_once 'dbh.inc.php';
    $user = $_SESSION['userid'];
    echo($user);

    $sql = "UPDATE users SET userHighScore = $highScore WHERE userId = $user;";

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
        header("location: ../leaderboard.php?error=stmtfailed");
        exit();
    }

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $highScore);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

}
?>
```

So when I run this, the getOutput function executes but the PHP function doesn't seem to execute. Maybe it is an error in the PHP function, I am not sure.

I think that `$user = $_SESSION['userid'];` doesn't work properly.

Comment: how, in the php, are you calling the function `gameOver`? I see it passed as an argument in the data for your ajax call but not how that ajax call is processed

Comment: Nowhere in your code do you actually call the 'gameOver' function in PHP. You need to process the POSTed data, and actually call the function found in your `functionname` parameter.

Comment: If that is truly the entire `myAjax.php` script, you're only defining the function, not calling it. If there is more to that script, then please include that in the question.

Comment: The variable `arguments` in your ajax function is an array - presumably that is a single value in the array or multiple? If it is single there should be no need for the array syntax and it'll ake the PHP processing easier

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: You have a misunderstand how PHP works. The browser makes a request to the webserver which executes the php script and sends the output back. You're not calling the function but the whole script.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I see. Tried fixing this with Quentin's answer but the function still doesn't seem to execute. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

You can't call a PHP *function* from JavaScript.

You can make an HTTP request to an HTTP endpoint. That HTTP endpoint can be handled by a PHP *program*. It can either *always* call the function or conditionally call it (based on the contents of `$_POST` for example).

e.g.

```
$functionname = $_POST['functionname'];
if ($functionname == "gameOver") {
    gameOver($_POST['arguments'][0]);
}
```

… but you should abstract things so the *data* you are sending isn't so tightly coupled with the *implementation* of the PHP.

(Note that your JS is expecting some JSON back in the response but your function doesn't output any. Make sure you deal with that too.)

Comment: it appears though that he is sending an http request to `myajax.php` but not processing the request correctly

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius — Yes, this answer explains how to handle the request correctly.

Comment: indeed it does @Quentin

Comment: Indeed, I don't understand that good what I'm doing. So if I add this code to my ```myAjax.php``` the function should be called correctly? Because I added it and it doesn't update the high score in the MySQL. That makes me think that maybe the function is not working correctly.

Comment: It works now. My mistake was that ```require_once 'dbh.inc.php';``` was in the folder Includes and I had not added it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST, $_POST['functionname'], $_POST['arguments'])) {
        switch($_POST['functionname']) {
            case 'gameOver' :
                gameOver($_POST['arguments'][0]);
            break;
            default:
                echo "Unknown method!";
            break;
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "No score posted!";
    }
```

Comment: Did you know that `isset($_POST['functionname'], $_POST['arguments'])` can take multiple parameter [The Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Comment: Also you might want to check the spelling of `breeak`